# How to get Vue.set working right in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

i get a vuejs error `Property or method "selectedVehicule" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive...`

i think this coming from `Vue.set` but what i did wrong

Here is my main.js file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    selectedVehicle: {},
  },
  mutations: {
    setSelectedVehicle (state, selectedVehicle) {
      Vue.set(state.selectedVehicle, 'items', 'dummy1')
      Vue.set(state.selectedVehicle, 'id', 'dummy2')
      Vue.set(state.selectedVehicle, 'kuzzleInfo', 'dummy3')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

And my component file where i read it:

```js
computed: {
    selectedVehicle (val) {
      return this.$store.state.selectedVehicle
    }
  },
  ...
```

And the other where i set it:

```js
computed: {
    selectedVehicule: {
      get: function () {
        return this.$store.state.selectedVehicle
      },
      set: function (newVal) {
        this.$store.commit('setSelectedVehicle', newVal)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is your getter ?

Comment: @Pawan Rai my getter is just my computed value which I use in the template balise

Answer (score 0):

fill your selectedVehicle with all the 3 properties in state object

```
state: {
    selectedVehicle: {
        items: '',
        id: '',
        kuzzleInfo: ''
    },
}
```

you could try it

Comment: Anyone have an idea ?